# 2006 Sequoia VSC TRAC, VSC off, and brake lights keep coming on

Tags: toyota, brakes, intermittent-problems, sequoia

The lights in the title come on at times and stay on for the duration of whatever trip I am taking. Sometimes they don't come on during driving and then they start up again for no apparent reason. My mechanic has looked at the readings which suggest many different causes, among them a possible brake master cylinder potential for failure. It just seems weird that all three lights come together most of the time although sometimes only the brake light comes on. Any ideas?

Comment: The very first thing to do would be to get the "codes" read from the brake control module, for anybody trying to help having a list of the codes will be a big help. Also, could you tell us which brake light? It might help if you could add a photo of the dash with the lights on.

Comment: All three systems are related. If anything in any single piece goes bad, all three lights can easily come on due to their functional relationship.

Comment: Anything related to your brakes is serious, so this is worth tracking down. The common link here is the ABS (anti-lock braking system), the ABS works by detecting the speed of each of the wheels on your car. If the system detects, a wheel that is spinning too fast or too slow, it can pass that information along to allow, for example, the traction control system to apply braking to help maintain traction. One place that you might start looking is at the condition of the ABS sensors at each wheel and the wiring to them. The power supply to the ABS and VSC systems would also be good to check.